# Print multiple Outputs stored in a vector with a Loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm new in R and coding in general...
I have computed multiple anova analysis on multiple columns (16 in total).
For that purpose, the method "Purr" helped me :

```
anova_results_5sector <- purrr::map(df_anova_ch[,3:18], ~aov(.x ~ df_anova_ch$Own_5sector))


summary(anova_results_5sector[[1]])
```

So the dumbest way to retrieve output (p-value, etc) is the following method

```
summary(anova_results_5sector$Env_Pillar)
summary(anova_results_5sector$Gov_Pillar)
summary(anova_results_5sector$Soc_Pillar)
summary(anova_results_5sector$CSR_Strat)
summary(anova_results_5sector$Comm)
summary(anova_results_5sector$ESG_Comb)
summary(anova_results_5sector$ESG_Contro)
summary(anova_results_5sector$ESG_Score)
summary(anova_results_5sector$Env_Innov)
summary(anova_results_5sector$Human_Ri)
summary(anova_results_5sector$Management)
summary(anova_results_5sector$Prod_Resp)
```

I've tried to use a loop :

```
for(i in 1:length(anova_results_5sector)){
  summary(anova_results_5sector$[i])
}
```

It didn't work, I dont know and did not find how to deal with $ in for loop

Here you have a look of the structure of the output vector
[Structure of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYScl.png)

I have tried several times with others methods, more or less complicated.  Often the examples found online are too simple and does not allow me to adapt to my data.
Any tips ?

Thank you and sorry for such an noobie question

Comment: Try without the `$` i.e. `anova_results_5sector[[i]]` or `for (i in anova_results_5sector) { summary(i) }` which will loop directly over the elements of your list.

Comment: Hello Stefan
First option : return this error message _Error in anova_results_5sector[i] : type 'list' d'indice incorrect_. Second option did not print anything =(

Comment: Hm Both options work fine. But you are right. We have to wrap inside `print()` when using a for loop. So. Better option would be `lapply(anova_results_5sector, summary)` or if you want your results as a tidy dataframe you could do `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(anova_results_5sector, broom::tidy), .id = "var")`

Comment: Hello Stefan , this exact line of code gave me the output for my 16 anova test `lapply(anova_results_5sector, summary)`. Exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you

Comment: And this line of code works perfectly to extract results and display in datafram,. I have no idea i could use ``bind_rows` in this way ( with indented list of my output) `dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(anova_results_5sector, broom::tidy), .id = "var")` Thank you so much it's perfect, and I'm learning a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I use a loop for an analysis I like to store the results in a data.frame, it allows to keep a good overview. Since you did not provide a reproducible example I used the iris dataset:

```
data("iris")

#make a data frame to store the results with as many columns and rows as you need
anova_results <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
#one column per value you want to store and one row per anova you want to run
x <- c("number", "Mean_Sq", "p_value") #assign all values you want to store as column names
colnames(anova_results) <- x

anova_results$number <- 1:3 #assign numers for each annova you want to run, eg. 3
```

In the loop you can now extract the results of the anova that you are interested in, I use mean squares and p-value as an example, but you can of course add others. Don't forget to add a coulmn for other values you want to add.

```
for (i in 2:4){
  my_anova <- aov(iris[[1]] ~ iris[[i]]) 
  p <- summary(my_anova)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1] #extract the p value
  anova_results$p_value[anova_results$number == i-1] <- p
  mean <- summary(my_anova)[[1]][["Mean Sq"]][1] #extract the mean quares
  anova_results$Mean_Sq[anova_results$number == i-1] <- mean
}
View(anova_results)
```

Comment: I found your answer interesting but I've already performed multiple anova requested  : my main problem is to extract p-value for exemple from the weird structure of the output I've just upload on my question. 
I've tried your code but doen't get same results and I can't change paramaters of the anova at my convenience.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your code entirely, because I don't know the original data structure. But if I understand correctly, you just want to access the output in the lists you already created. So the map() command always creats a list and as visible in the picture you added, the results are stored in the list elements. You can access them by: `summary(anova_results_5sector[[1]])` this way you get all the anova statistics you get when using the summary() comand on a regulat single anova.

Comment: If you now want to store for example all p-values in a list you can use this code, "Pr(>F)" can be replaced by all statistics that occur in the output: `p_values <- list()`

`for (i in 1:16) {
  x[i] <- summary(anova_results_5sector[[1]])[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
}`
`x`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, my output is like indented a lists in lists. (you can check the link to the screenshot that summarize the situation. So this line of code doesnt help in retrieving output for each anova (16 in total) `summary(anova_results_5sector[[1]])`. But what stefan bring up there seems to work nicely. Thank you very much for your help cucumber, I think your solution with creation of preexistent data frame to store results will surely help in my next analyses !